# spring cloud dataflow http - enforce SSL

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have SCDF deployed on PCF environment (1.2.3 Release)
I need to enforce communication only for trusted parties for HTTP endpoint;

On the first approach - I have installed 3rd party certificates on the PCF level;
SSL connection is stablished correctly - however communication on this endpoint  not using certificates is still possible (e.g. curl )

Based on my investigation I have found the following way

1. I have created trust store using openssl /keytool
2. I have setup the simple stream as "http | log"

for deploy http app - I am using following properties

```
app.http.logging.level.org.springframework.integration=DEBUG
app.http.management.security.enabled=true
app.http.server.ssl.client-auth=need
app.http.server.ssl.enabled=true
app.http.server.ssl.trust-store=https://static_file_URL/SCDF.truststore
app.http.server.ssl.trust-store-password=<pass>
```

however
the module does not start with the following error message "Resource location must not be null"

```
[OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.http.source.rabbit.HttpSourceRabbitApplication.main(HttpSourceRabbitApplication.java:29) [classes/:na]
[OUT] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
[OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [app/:na]
[OUT] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource location must not be null
```

can you advise me how to configure http module to achieve this goal?

best regards
Wojtek

Comment: How are the `app.http....` properties supplied in the DSL? Are they supplied as deployment properties or is that resolved from config-server?

Comment: Hello Saby
Thanks for reply.
I tried both option - explicitly set deployment parameter in the stream definition or add deployment properties.
result was the same as described

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Can you also upload the entire stacktrace in a file or as a gist? It would be useful to troubleshoot.

Comment: we managed to have SSL validation enforced  working on locally run apps when we embedded certificates inside the client app and then server part ;
as there is ongoing activities to check on various components variant for SSL termination - (HAproxy, goRouter and  TCProuter as example) when apps are running in PCF - then we wanted to apply final solution after review;
thank you